# Is there any LLVM pass to check whether LLVM IR is in SSA form?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Is there any built in LLVM pass to check whether the generated IR is in SSA form or not?

For example: If the IR was compiled using mem2reg option , we will get IR in SSA form. Can we check in our pass , whether mem2reg was used or not?

Comment: Even if it's not, it is as easy a iterating through every instruction, looking for `phi` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

See `llvm::verifyModule`, `llvm::verifyFunction`, or `llvm::createVerifierPass`. cf http://llvm.org/doxygen/Verifier_8cpp_source.html .

See also opt's `-verify-each` option and the Verify* fields of `PassManagerBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to know which LLVM pass is being used.

In that case, you can run opt with `-debug-pass=Arguments`, or `-mllvm -debug-pass=Arguemnt` if you are using clang.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the code to human readable `.ll` and then try to find if there are phi nodes in the IR code. Assuming you have the bitcode

`llvm-dis <file.bc> -o file.ll 
cat file.ll | grep phi`